How to prove the sum of limits theorem for a finite N number of limits?
I was reading a book with sequences and it proved that given two sequences $A$ and $B$ which both converge, then $\lim(A+B) =\lim(A)+\lim(B)$.
However, the sum of $N$ limits $$\lim(A_1+A_2+A_3+\dots)=\lim(A_1)+\lim(A_2)+\lim(A_3)+\dots= a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots$$ was left to the reader.
I tried the following:
Given by the definition of limit, for $n=1,\dots, N$, there exists a $K_n(\epsilon)$ such that for all $k>K_n(\epsilon),$ $|A_{n,k}-a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{N}$. Then taking $k>\max(K_1,K_2,K_3,...K_N)$, by the triangle inequality:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^NA_{n,k} -\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right|<\sum_{n=1}^N |A_{n,k}-a_n|< \frac{\epsilon}{N}+\frac{\epsilon}{N}+\frac{\epsilon}{N}+\frac{\epsilon}{N}+...+\frac{\epsilon}{N} = \epsilon.$$
However, I don't know if this is correct because the book suggested we use induction but I have not and I don't know if I have supposed something I shouldn't have.

Okay, then should I skip the sum of limits and just keep the definition of a limit? I edited it now. Is it correct?

I don't get the induction.

The application,.

Does this answer your question? Limit of a sum is the sum of the limits: proof by induction It is written there for functions, but you can easily transpose to your sequences: replace $x$ with $k$, $\to a$ with $\to\infty$, $f_i (i=1,\dots,n)$ with $A_n(n=1,\dots,N)$, etc.

Welcome to MSE. Your proof is fine. For a proof using induction, we generally have some statement $P(k)$ dependent on $k$ and we want to prove, that $P$ holds for all natural numbers. In induction, we show that there exists some $k_0$ such that $P(k_0)$ holds true. If we then can show that for $k\geq k_0$ we have $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$, then $P$ holds for all $k\geq k_0$. In your particular case, we have
$$
P(k) = \left( \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^k A_{i,n} = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i\right).
$$
My notation is a bit abusive, but $P(k)$ is the statement, that the limit of the sum of $k$ convergent sequences is the sum of their limits. The base case $k=1$ is true by default, but the more interesting one is of course $k=2$. This can be shown using your argument. Notice now, that $\tilde A = A_1 + \cdots + A_k$ is a convergent sequence whose limit is $a_1+\cdots a_k$, by our induction assumption. In the induction step, we now consider
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\tilde A_n + A_{k+1,n}).
$$
From here, I believe you know how to finish the proof.
